# Python input datatype handling

Tags: python, validation, input, error-handling

I spent a good hour or more looking for the answer on here. I have found a few things that help, but do not answer my question specifically. I am using Python 3.3.3. I am a novice so please be gentle.

I am trying to create a program that takes a user input, but then I need to do a check to see what datatype that input is, and then based on that datatype take a certain course of action.

Any string besides those found in this list:

`valid_help_string_list = ['\'help\'', '\'HELP\'', 'help', 'HELP']`

should result in the printing of:

'please enter a valid entry' or something to that effect.

Any integer (over 0 but under 500) should have float() used on it to make the rows line up.

Any float (over 0.0 but under 500.0) is valid.

For the sake of this project I am assuming nobody using this will weigh under 100 lbs or over 500.

Anything not falling within those categories should also yield the same "please enter a valid response" error message to the user.

I think it's simple enough of a project to take on for a novice. The program is meant to allow you to input your weight and then creates a pictogram based on that weight and saves it all on the next open line of the .txt file I have set up for it. Or if you want to see the legend for the pictogram, you should be able to type help in any variation found in that list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user input will be a string by default, so we need to check whether it could become an integer or float. As you want to turn the integers in floats anyway, there's no need to do anything complex:

```
def validate_input(val, min_v=100, max_v=500):
    try:
        val = float(val)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid entry")
    else:
        if not min_v < val <= max_v:
            print("Value should be between {} and {}".format(min_v, max_v))
        else:
            return val
    return False
```

Now your calling loop can read:

```
while True:
    val = input("...")
    if val in valid_help_string_list:
        # print help
    else:
        val = validate_input(val)
        if val:
            break
# use val
```

Note that this relies on the return from `validate_input` being either `False` or a number larger than `0`; Python will interpret a zero return as `False` and not reach the `break`, so I recommend keeping `min_v >= 0`.

Comment: I tried using this. It works but not as I expected. Very close though. Perhaps I am just that inexperienced, I cannot make it work properly. I enter under 100 and it just accepts it, I enter over 500 and it accepts it, when I enter 100-500 it says that the number needs to be between 100 and 500.

Comment: Apologies, I missed out a crucial `not`. Edited.

Comment: THANK YOU! I am proud of myself for recognizing that line as the offender, I tried multiple things but that totally slipped my mind as a possibility. I really appreciate it.